# Can't find Top command in kubernetes pod

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I have a spring-boot application deployed on Kubernetes, I want see the top process on my pod as top is not available currently. Docker image we have used:

```
    FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest
    RUN mkdir /opt/app
    COPY myapp.jar /opt/app
    CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/app/myapp.jar"]
```

Enable top related commands in Kubernetes pod.

Comment: you obviously need to install `top` into the docker image

Comment: How and why will your application run `top`?  What would you expect it to show besides the single `java` process?

Comment: login into the Kubernetes pod using exec -it command and run the top command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install top through below command. But you must have root access on pod to run this command.

```
microdnf install procps
```